# Suppose that $90°<\theta<180°$. What is the sign of $\sin\frac{2}{\theta}$?

Tags: trigonometry

This is the question in our assignment, but I just want to know if this question really makes sense.
Wouldn't be the unit inside the $\sin$ be $\frac{1}{°}$ so it doesn't make sense? Should I convert it to radians and just continue?

Comment: As stated, the query is gibberish, because the query's title indicates (in effect) that the domain of the sine function is an angle rather than a dimensionless number.  That is fine, as far as it goes, but when angles have a specific unit of measurement, like a degree, the notion of (for example) $\frac{1}{1^{\circ}}$ is undefined.  Similarly, while 1 foot is a measure of length, $\frac{1}{1 foot}$ is undefined.  ...see next comment

Comment: Although dimensional analysis (e.g miles per hour) will frequently have a dimensioned number in the denominator, you are (in effect) expressing the ratio of two dimensioned numbers. This is totally different from having a dimensioned number in the denominator and a dimensionless number in the numerator.  Certainly you can arbitrarily assign a meaning to (for example) $\frac{1}{1^{\circ}}$ that allows the problem to be meaningful, but you are just as justified as saying that $\frac{1}{1^{\circ}}$ = 1 *giraffe*.

Comment: Can you give context of the question?  This seems.... ridiculous.

Comment: @fleablood I infer that the context is someone's *right* parietal lobe.

Comment: Our teacher is the one who is making the questions (I'm in 10th grade) and probably isn't  really that good at this so he might have thought that still made sense, I don't really know he just put the question there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an angle has no unit, it is in radians. Since angle units are convertible, we may as well convert $\theta$ to radians – $\frac\pi2<\theta<\pi$ – and find that over that interval $\sin\frac2\theta$ is **positive**.